# Porting custom job from GCP AI Platform to Vertex AI - how to get state and logs of job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I am porting custom job training from gcp AI Platform to Vertex AI.
I am able to start a job, but can't find how to to get the status and how to stream the logs to my local client.

For AI Platform I was using this to get the state:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(keyFile, scopes=scopes)
ml_apis = discovery.build("ml","v1", credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
x = ml_apis.projects().jobs().get(name="projects/%myproject%/jobs/"+job_id).execute()  # execute http request
return x['state']
```

And this to stream the logs:

```
cmd = 'gcloud ai-platform jobs stream-logs ' + job_id
```

This does not work for Vertex AI job. What is the replacement code?

Comment: Ok, solved the state part:     
cmd = "gcloud ai custom-jobs describe --region=europe-west4 --format=json " + job_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this command for streaming logs :

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs stream-logs 123 --region=europe-west4
```

123 is the **ID** of the custom job for this case, you can add glcoud wide flags such as --format as well.

You can visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/stream-logs) for more details about this command and additional flags available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `google-cloud-aiplatform` SDK, you can get the model training status via [job.state](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJob#google_cloud_aiplatform_CustomContainerTrainingJob_state)

Example:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

# Initialize aiplatform
aiplatform.init(project="xxx", location="asia-east1", staging_bucket="xx_gcs_bucket")

# Create custom container train job
job = aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJob(
    display_name="abc-model",
    container_uri="asia-east1-docker.pkg.dev/xxx/xxx",
)

# Start the training
model = job.submit(
    replica_count=1,
    machine_type="n1-standard-16"
)

print(job.state)
# <PipelineState.PIPELINE_STATE_PENDING: 3>
```